# Is dynamically changing a datasource possible in arcgis js api?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dynamic

I've posted a [related question](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/60378-accessing-stored-procedures?p=210974#post210974) is in the ArcGIS Desktop forums, but hasn't gotten any replies yet. In that case, I would like tackle this in another way, which is dynamically changing a datasource using arcgis js api. Is this possible?

To give some detail, the layers defined in my mapservice are joined with another view through oledb. Will the class QueryDataSource be able to do this, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at ArcGIS 10.1 by using dynamic workspaces. Just define a workspace with an attached ID, then you can pull any layer or table in the workspace as a datasource. You can run queries against that dynamic workspace datasource or  use a renderer to render the data source.
The data source can be vector or raster, though it is not that clear how you define the renderer for a raster data source.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I'm using only 10. It's something to look forward to, anyway.